# Unable to achieve same AutoLayout results in each simulator?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-simulator

[image]

I suppose a picture is worth a thousand words.  So I have the storyboard set up using auto layout, in (I'm assuming) an iPhone 6  storyboard.  When I test using the iPhone 5 simulator, the result does not match my storyboard.  I am unsure if my universal image asset is too big (550x129) or my settings using the simulator are incorrect.  Would you be able to explain why my simulator is showing my misconstrued layout?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears your only constraint is to align the x axis to the center.  Click the button that looks like this |-[ ]-| and set all of the spacing constraints to 0.  This will specify that there should be no space between your image and the edge of the screen, no matter what size.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a subView.
- Setup the subView as the container of your assets.
- Add autolayout constrains to subview.

  - Add the assets inside the Container subView and add autolayout constrains.
  - Or - Add a Vertical Stack View and add your assets in there. Setup the autolayout constrains of the Vertical Stack View